# Получаю ошибку [: missing `]' при выполнение скрипта

Tags: bash, unix

Всем привет. Вроде как не особо сложный скрипт, но на строку `export CMD_STATUS=2` ругается `` [: missing `]' ``. Вот кусок листинга скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD_STATUS=1

check () {
  if [ $1 -ne 0 ]; then
      export CMD_STATUS=2
  fi
}

EXECUTION_LOG="$DIR/log/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S).log"

exec > >(tee $EXECUTION_LOG) 2>&1

ATTEMPT=1
IN_ATTEMPTS=10

while [ "$ATTEMPT" -le "$IN_ATTEMPTS" ]
do

  CMD_STATUS=1

  $DIR/lock.sh 
  check $?

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    #выполняем различные команды (запускаем sh-скрипты)
    check $?

    $DIR/unlock.sh
    check $?
  fi

  if [ $CMD_STATUS -eq 2 ]; then
    let "ATTEMPT += IN_ATTEMPTS"
  else
    let "ATTEMPT += 1"        
  fi
done

EXIT_CODE=0
if [ $СMD_STATUS -eq 2 ]; then
  EXIT_CODE=1
fi

exit $EXIT_CODE
```

Ну и что я не так сделал? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если Вы о `check () { ...`, то у         меня в `Linux wubu 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS \n \l` тестик с копипастом `check () { ...` нормально работает...

Comment: Да, речь идет о `check () { ...`. У меня RHEL 6.4

Comment: ошибка явно происходит в предыдущей строке, начинающейся с `if`. проверьте, что именно передаётся фукнции первым аргументом. например, добавьте первой строкой внутри функции `check()`: `echo "аргумент='$1'"`

Comment: Проверьте, что между `0` и `]` в рабочем скрипте и в самом деле пробел (если так, то посмотрите чему равна переменная IFS (The  Internal  Field  Separator ))

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую "погонять" скрипт на разных данных.

Comment: Возьмите за правило хорошего тона все скрипты начинать с `#!/bin/sh -efu`, узнаете много нового про 95% г*вноскриптов. Shell — трудный язык.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko а можно поподробнее про `#!/bin/sh -efu`? Прошу ткнуть носом в какую-нибудь статью или описание опции. Спасибо!

Comment: Да уж куда проще — `man sh`. Коротко: а) использовать переносимое подмножество (исключаем башизмы и прочие расширения), б) вываливаться при ошибках, в) все переменные должны быть определены, и г) запрет `glob()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто возьмите за правило всегда заключать аргументы в кавычки:

```
if [ "$1" -ne 0 ]; then
```

Comment: Ну, тут это совсем ни при чем (сравниваются числа). А для строк, да, стоит. Причем даже лучше добавлять один и тот же символ в обеих частях, например `if [ "X$1" == "X"`  ]` для проверки, что `$1` пусто.

Comment: Вы правы. Если бы это был случай с кавычками, то ошибка была бы `[: -ne: unary operator expected`. Чтобы добиться ошибки как у автора вопроса, нужно убрать закрывающую квадратную скобку: `if [ $? -ne $1 ; then` Вероятно, автор нам показал старый код либо новую ошибку. Еще есть вариант по доктору Хаузу, что он банально нас обманул :)

Comment: Не обманывал я вас :| Со скобками все в порядке.